# Odd behavior when creating a new window in WPF using another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to make a simple application in WPF which will open a new window in a thread it's behaving oddly.

```
ArrayList formArray = new ArrayList();
Thread th;
Window1 vd;

public void Start()
{
    vd = new Window1();

    formArray.Add(vd);
    vd.ShowDialog();
}

public void StartCall()
{
    th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartCall();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Window1)(formArray[0])).Show();
}
```

Window1 code is

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

When trying to open it again, it just throws an error `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.

When trying to use dispatcher.. invoke... all these things didn't help.
To make it even weirder, this same code worked in a Windows Forms application.

Maybe it's related to  this line? `th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`?

It might be this guys, but if I won't add it, it will also fail with an error that

`Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.`

Comment: but im telling u bro same code in windows forms it works!!! @Sheridan

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It's very uncommon to open a window on another thread.

Comment: @CharlesMager im working on a c# network  program bro

Comment: @Sheridan You can if the background thread was the thread which created the Window. It happens to be the case here.

Comment: Where is this error thrown?

Comment: That's not a particularly compelling reason to open a window on another thread.  Why not open the window on the same thread?  What are you trying to achieve by opening it on another?

Comment: You should always try to keep your windows on the same thread, you can do the work inside the form on another thread.

Comment: Best advise we can give is don't mess up with UI and worker thread. Just show the UI in main thread. Make life simple.

Comment: Try adding `th.IsBackground = true;` in your `StartCall` method. Have you seen the [Threading Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN?

Comment: @CharlesMager bro i use socket to listen which works on thread and everytime a client connect i open a new chat video on this thread... im not bored.... i use it cuz it necessary  Sheridan yeah bro and i tried isbackground also... but as i said guys the most weird part,u can try by urself take this code and paste on new winform application and it will work!!

Comment: It's not that weird - this isn't WinForms.  The issue is most likely that you're calling `Show` from a different thread.  Invoking via the Window's dispatcher (`((Window1)formArray[0]).Dispatcher`) is likely to resolve your current issue, though expect many more!

Comment: @Charles Mager aleardy tried dispatcher bro.... not working :(:(

Comment: Don't create multiple UI threads.  Use a single UI thread, and do all of your UI work in that one thread.  Do any long running non-UI work you have in a non-UI thread, rather than doing non-UI work in your UI thread and creating a second thread to do UI work.  You're making things way harder on yourself than you need to.

Comment: @user3548681: dispatcher *does* work if you use it properly - see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `.Show` on your window from a thread other than the one it was created on (that's basically what the error message is telling you!). Fortunately, as you suggested, this is what the dispatcher is for: to marshal calls onto the correct thread. But you have to use the correct dispatcher for the job!

Each control in WPF (including a Window) has a `.Dispatcher` property that gets the Dispatcher *for that control's thread*. My guess is that you were using the one from your main window when trying to re-open the dialog - which is the wrong one. Instead, if you use this in your `Button_Click` you will have more luck:

```
var window = (Window1)formArray[0];
window.Dispatcher.Invoke(window.Show);  // note: use the dispatcher that belongs to the window you're calling
```

(NOTE: this isn't to say that this is a typically useful/recommended design pattern. In fact, it's often going to cause more problems than it solves. But, it's certainly something you *can* choose to do.)

Comment: Would the downvoter explain themselves? I believe I've posted a working answer to the problem at hand (while also explaining that it's typically a bad idea).

Comment: ty bro i really appreiciate ur help i tried ur suggestion and when i trigger the button click the ui just getting freeze... it's hangs bro...

Comment: @user3548681: are you debugging it? What line does it freeze on? Freezing likely means you've hit another issue related to your use of threading...

Comment: @Dan: your answer is precise in general. However, in his specific case, he did not init the Dispatcher loop, resulting in Invoke hang the application.

Comment: @EledraNguyen: what do you mean by "init the Dispatcher loop?"

Comment: You can check the URL i posted in the edit version.  That's my guess for the situation. If someone can explain in detail that would definetly be a great help

Comment: You don't need to "init" anything. Here is a pastebin I've made with a minimal LinqPad example, which works just fine: http://pastebin.com/Y6s1Knvb

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Added the force run on dispatcher on your thread.
I also added a Display method to show the dialog depending on the dispatcher who is calling. Hope that help !

Also, as explained here: [Dispatcher.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You should shutdown the dispatcher of the corresponding thread when you are done.

MainWindow:

```
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartCall();
    }

    ArrayList formArray = new ArrayList();
    Window1 vd;
    Thread th;

    public void Start()
    {
        vd = new Window1();
        formArray.Add(vd);
        vd.ShowDialog();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); //ok this is magic
    }

    public void StartCall()
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartCall();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Window1)(formArray[0])).Display();            
    }
```

Window1:

```
    void Window1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)Display);
            return;
        }

        this.Show();
    }
```

Comment: this will work even without the owner property dude.. all the point of my question was how to do this with thread cuz im using it in a socket program ...@Eledra Nguyen

Comment: You don't need to use `test`; you can just call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Display)` and it'll work.

Comment: @Dan: BeginInvoke need a delegate.

Comment: Ah yes; `Invoke` will accept an `Action` but `BeginInvoke` won't. You can do this though: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)Display);`

Comment: Awesome ! Changed the answer as your suggestion.